# Why does the text inside a button overlapses when I added a background img?

Tags: html, css

Update: I've updated my code (thanks to, Kodos Johnson). But I have another problem with the padding for the background image.

When I tried adding a background image inside my button, the text inside it moves outside the button. Can someone please help me? My code is below:

```html
<div>           
  <button type="button" id="secondBarButton">See How It Works</button>
</div>
```

---[Update 2: I want to add padding or margin for the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA6kE.png)

```css
#secondBarButton {
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-image: url(images/button.png);
}
```

[I cannot make the text move back inside the button and center.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ocfot.png)

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle or something so we can see the html awell.

Comment: Please provide the html part too.

Comment: Based on your CSS, it doesn't look like you have a background image. It looks like you have a `<img>` inside your button and you have a fixed-height button. The `<img>` will push down the text. You probably want to use `background-image: url(/path/to/image.jpg)` in your `#secondBarButton` instead.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Thank you so much for the help. The background-image:url works. However, padding and margin don't help me make it move right.

Comment: How about the real url to this background-image? It would make things easier on us and less work for you in the future.

Comment: Use the `background-position` property to position the image. Specifically for your case, do `background-position: 15px 15px;` AND `background-repeat:no-repeat;`. Play around with the `background-position` values to get the spacing you want.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about using a background image for a simple icon. Use icons from FontAwesome, the particular one used on this button is:

> [`fa-play-circle`](http://fontawesome.io/icon/play-circle/)

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>Button</title>
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <style>
    #btn1 {
      position: relative;
      width: 300px;
      height: 50px;
      border-radius: 25px;
      background-color: white;
      border: 1px solid #0070BA;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 0.8em;
      color: #0070BA;
      line-height: 1;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .fa {
      position: absolute;
      left: 2px;
      top: -2px;
    }
    #btn1:hover {
      background-color: #0070BA;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      color: #fff;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <button id="btn1">
    <i class='fa fa-4x fa-play-circle'></i> See How It Works
  </button>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing the HTML would help a lot. Looks like your image is forcing a line break. Have u tried sectioning the image and text with col? That might be a quick and dirty fix to your problem